# error measure (of ML agos) that takes confidence into account

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

when calculating the error measure such as mean absolute error, we use the real values and the predicted values. Many machine learning algorithms can give a confidence measure of each value being predicted. Is there a standard error or correlation measure that takes this confidence into account, and penalizes high confidence errors more than low confidence ones? I can write such a function - eg: weighted avg(abs(error)) weighted by confidence. But I'm interested in whether such a measure is standard and known to be in use.

Comment: I'll try to do a write-up later, but if you incorporate prior variance terms for your regression parameters, then weighted least squares gives you exactly this.